# Is there a way to add more than one dashboard to Azure Devops per team?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'd like to add a second dashboard for our team. My idea was having a dashboard to show specific sprint information, and another dashboard so that I can see more general information, consolidating metrics from all sprints. Is there any way to do that? I already checked permissions and all of us should be able to do it. When I try adding another one, I see the Create button greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

By reference to this doc: [Add, rename, and delete dashboards in Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/dashboards?view=azure-devops),
[image]
Therefore, please check whether you are the team admin with Basic access level.
[image]

Comment: Hi Szczepko, Are you fine? Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.

Comment: Hi, no, in fact it didn't. Option isn't available, which is weird.